# How to read crash reports from Developer Console

Tags: android, debugging, crash-reports, developer-console

I'm trying to track down the source of a bug, based on a crash report submitted by a user, and have come to the conclusion that I need some basic training on how to interpret a crash report.

As an example, the crash report is as follows:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:525)
    at com.cloud3squared.meteogram.MeteogramService.cacheFileName(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    cacheBaseName(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    getAppWidgetId(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    createAdhocWidgetUpdateIntent(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    setupBasicClickStuff(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    setAdhocAppWidgetAlarm(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    setNextClockWidgetUpdateAlarm(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    cancelAppWidgetAlarm(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    cancelAppWidgetAlarms(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    logAction$3aaf2084(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    logActionAgainstAllWidgets$62dc3a79(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    updateAppWidget(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    showButtons(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    hideButtons(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    fetchOk(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    getViewId(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    putBitmapIntoWidget(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    lngNow(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    showNotification(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    showMessageInWidget(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    sharpen(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    removeFromRequestsList(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    removeFromRequestsList$204347ff(MeteogramService.java)
                                                                           MeteogramService.java)
                                                    displayStuffInWidget(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    access$000(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    access$100(MeteogramService.java)
                                                    access$300(MeteogramService.java)
    at com.cloud3squared.meteogram.MeteogramService$GetServerWidgetAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MeteogramService.java)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Is this showing the order of calls leading up to the `NumberFormatException`, and if so, in what order?  Do I read the `at` lines from bottom to top?  What is `access` nested inside `MeteogramService`?... there is no `access` method in that class.  How do I determine inside which function the `NumberFormatException` actually occurs?  Logically I would say inside `cacheFileName` but there is nothing in there that might lead to such an exception... the parsing of a `String` to an `int` happens before that... the parsed int is simply passed into `cacheFileName`.

Any help gratefully received.

EDIT

Further code snippets to refer to in comments below:

```
static String cacheFileName(Context context, int appWidgetId, int pxWidth, int pxHeight) {
    String fileName = cacheBaseName(appWidgetId) + "_" + pxWidth + "x" + pxHeight + ".png";
    logAction(context, appWidgetId, "cacheFileName " + fileName, TAG);
    return fileName;
}

static String cacheBaseName(int appWidgetId) {
    return (appWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) ? "widget_" : "widget_" + appWidgetId;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the exception stack is showing the order of calls.  The top most one (invalidInt) threw the exception. I'm not too sure about all the methods names listed on after the cacheFileName, perhaps a Java expert can comment.  The method to look forward will be the one called by onPostExecute.  To debug,  I would just generally look around in MeteograomService.java for calls to valueOf(String).  Hopefully there are not too many. Make sure to try/catch each

Comment: it has to do with your widget, when it was being updated in your messagegram service

Comment: Are you using ProGuard?

Comment: Yes I'm using proguard, though uploading a mapping file for each release.

Answer (score 3):

The error is in `MeteogramService.java` file.

The error `NumberFormatException` is due to an invalid int value, which is possibly because of passing a string or invalid variable into an int.

The list of class names or method names is the order from top to bottom in which the variable has been accessed. Verify if you are passing an int, and in case if it is user defined value, then use a try/catch block and show toast whenever they enter a non-int value.

Answer (score 3):

You have to read it BOTH from *top to bottom* and *bottom to top*.

It's typically more specific from the top to broader at the bottom.

**From the TOP**: you will find the precise cause of exception

Which in this case is `java.lang.NumberFormatException` which blows up at `cacheFileName`'s `cacheBaseName`

**From the BOTTOM**: you will find the general area of the problem

`GetServerWidgetAsyncTask.onPostExecute`

What this looks like to me is that it could be some value finished in the background work in the AsyncTask is improperly formatted and used as an int in onPostExecute.

Where I would start off is to debug the values of: `pxWidth`, `pxHeight`, and `appWidgetId` in `String fileName = cacheBaseName(appWidgetId) + "_" + pxWidth + "x" + pxHeight + ".png";`

`Integer.valueOf` means it was probably trying to parse a string into an int, example: String "13" into int 13.

Out of those 3 variables, the most probable relation is the `appWidgetId` since there is another tip about `getAppWidgetId`. But to be sure, log all 3! =)

Answer (score 2):

> Is this showing the order of calls leading up to the NumberFormatException

Yes this stack trace is definitely showing you the order of calls leading upto the exception. Read your stack trace from bottom to top to know the order of method calls -

> What is access nested inside MeteogramService?... there is no access method in that class

these access methods are automatically generated methods to access members of a outer class from inner class. For more details check this [video](https://realm.io/news/360andev-jake-wharton-java-hidden-costs-android/?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=5ba9a634ac-Android_Weekly_220&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-5ba9a634ac-337964073) by Jake Wharton.

> How do I determine inside which function the NumberFormatException actually occurs

Check all the method calls in the stack trace. The top ones will tell you from which method the exception is thrown first. So if you check the stack trace, method calls in lines 2 to 4 are from Integer.java class which is a class not defined by you but the exception is initiated from this class. Now if you come to line 5, it clearly tells you that the next method call is `MeteogramService.cacheFileName()`. So the exception has arised when you try to do something from this method.

> there is nothing in there that might lead to such an exception

Read your stack trace carefully. In the very first line it says `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""`. It means you are passing empty string or "" to the integer class. Now if you check the line before `MeteogramService.cacheFileName()` it says `java.lang.Integer.valueOf()` method has been called by you.

Hence the conclusion is you are calling valueOf() method on and empty String which is not a valid Integer and hence the `NumberFormatException`

Comment: I'm still confused about the order in which the list should be read.  If it's bottom to top, then the exception has to occur in `cacheFileName()`.  But I've added the code for that function into my question, and there is no reference in that function to `Integer.valueOf()`... not even in `cacheBaseName()` called by that function.  The only calls to `Integer.valueOf()` are in `showNotification()` and `removeFromRequestsList()` which are much further down the list.  So, again, what is the proper way to read the ordering?

Comment: @Polarbear0106 which methods?

Comment: cacheFileName and cacheBaseName

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others,

Typically with crash reports, you want to look for the exception, in this case a `NumberFormatException`, and then for your class package name.

Assuming your package is `com.cloud3squared.meteogram.`, the problem is from your Meteogram Service and you are using `Integer.parseInt()` wrong.

Note that for `Integer.parseInt()`, you need a string that has a number in it like "3" or "5". If it doesn't have this, the method will crash with a `NumberFormatException`. I don't see that method call in your `cacheFileName()` class so I recommend you search through getAppWidgetID() and other method calls through the stack trace.